# What needs to be changed to successfully move an XML configuration for spring-data-redis 1.8.15 to 2.1.0?

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I'm attempting to update an existing application that makes use of spring-data-redis 1.8.15.RELEASE to the 2.1.0. RELEASE.  This application uses an XML-based configuration and was created well before Spring Boot, so I'm not able to use documentation that utilizes more modern Spring and Spring Boot configuration code.

Before changing the version of spring-data-redis, the application was able to be compiled and run successfully, using redis for a variety of purposes, including spring-session.  After updating the version of spring-data-redis, though, when I attempt to run the application, I receive an exception telling me that the JedisConnectionFactory bean can no longer be instantiated.

It's not clear to me, from the documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/), of what I need to change to move past this exception.  The documentation seems to show an XML example of the JedisConnectionFactory bean being instantiated similarly to how this code currently does.  I have read from other resources/sites that I may now need to create a RedisStandaloneConfiguration bean in some relation to the JedisConnectionFactory bean, but I haven't been able to find a clear example on how to do that.

Can anyone help me with the configuration and let me know what I need to change to have my application run properly?

#### Snippet from pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.15.RELEASE</version>
    <!--want to move to <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>-->
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

#### Snippet from application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">                
<context:annotation-config/>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:app.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="keySerializer" class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer"/>
<bean id="valueSerializer" class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer"/>
<bean id="hashKeySerializer" class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer"/>
<bean id="hashValueSerializer" class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer"/>

<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name = "hostName" value = "${redisHostName}"/>
    <property name = "port" value ="${redisPort}"/>
    <property name = "usePool" value = "true" />
</bean>

<!-- redis template definition -->
<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">
    <property name = "connectionFactory" ref = "jedisConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name = "keySerializer" ref = "keySerializer"/>
    <property name = "valueSerializer" ref = "valueSerializer"/>
    <property name = "hashKeySerializer" ref = "hashKeySerializer"/>
    <property name = "hashValueSerializer" ref = "hashValueSerializer"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

**The Exception:**

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jedisConnectionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1842)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisStandaloneConfiguration.<init>(RedisStandaloneConfiguration.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.<init>(JedisConnectionFactory.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.<init>(JedisConnectionFactory.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: Which version of `spring-core` are you using?

Comment: The code uses 4.2.5.RELEASE as its version of spring-core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a mismatch between the Spring libraries that you're using. I think you'll be seeing this problem if you're using a version of `spring-core` less than 5.x. `spring-data-redis` has a dependency on the `5.1.0` versions of other Spring libraries. You might have to check your other dependencies.

Comment: Can you point to any documentation that can help determine what the minimum versions are for the various versions of spring-data-redis?

Comment: Check the Requirements section in each version's reference manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#requirements

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed that section when looking at the documentation.